# Retrieve data from Salesforce using Django

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app

I am trying to integrate salesforce *Rest API with Django*, so for hours I have been trying to figure out the *endpoint* which it exposes, I have learned to create records but how do I access those records as the URL mentioned in docs is

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account,
```

what is "yourinstance" here, any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

when I tried to access the above URL in thunder client it gave me this error
(new to salesforce)

```
Couldn't resolve the hostname to an IP address, Verify Url: https://trial65.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check how to [Apply an OAuth Authorization Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm) (as it is not clear how you are authenticating to the target org)

once you figure this part out, you will quickly notice that the
instance is easily retrievable (basically, your salesforce subdomain+domain) and once you are able to retrieve an access token, you should be able to refer to the  [User Interface API Quick Start](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_quick_start.htm) for retrieving data.

feel free to update your post for further clarification(s)

Comment: ok so I have done the authorization flow part and also have the access token , url i am trying to connect ` https://d5g00000cr5k7eal-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/5005g00000DlvEDAAZ` but it is giving me this error now `[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "Could not find a match for URL"
    }
]` in postman

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce instance refers to the server that your Salesforce organization lives on. Many Salesforce orgs (also referred to as an "instance") live together on the same server, a method of server management called "multi-tenancy".

Generally the instance will be something like na1.salesforce.com.

To find your instance name your organization under  Setup->Company information  as shown below.

[image]

Please find the below knowledge article for more details on it.

[How to find the instance information](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=What-instance-am-I-using-1327107595509&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1)